# Why does this equivalence relation give a torus?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X=[0,1]^2$ and $(0,a)\sim(1,a), \ (b,0)\sim(b,1) \Rightarrow X/\sim \ \cong (S^1)^2$. I don't see why $X/\sim$ is torus, can someone explain?

Comment: Is your definition of a torus $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: If so, what do you think of $E:[0,1]^2\to( \mathbb{S}^1)^2$ that maps $(s,t)$ to $(e^{2i\pi t}, e^{2i\pi s})$

Comment: The professor drew a picture of a doughnut and said, this is a torus. @A.Rod

Comment: Then Faraad Armwood's answer is better suited than mine to your questionning.

Answer (score 3):

Convince yourself that it produces the following gluing indicated on the boundaries. The pictures show the gluing to give a torus.

[image]

Comment: Did you make the picture yourself or did you find it somewhere?

Comment: Found it. I wasn't that clever, but do you understand how the quotient corresponds to that gluing?

Comment: Well I would explain it as, $(0,a)\sim(1,a)$ tells that we can think of the boundary as "the same", that is being on $(0,a)$ can be though of as the same as being on $(1,a)$ for arbitrary $a$. That is why we can "glue" it togethere.

Comment: Not think of it as the same. In the quotient they are the same. Does this answer your question?

Comment: The first cyan arrow corresponds to $(0,a) \sim (1,a)$, and the second cyan arrow to $(b,0) \sim (b,1)$.

Comment: Yes, I understand. In the quotient its the same.