# Understanding 2-torus by square and that orientation

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I have a problem

> > Let $K = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; 1 \leq x,y \leq 1 \}$ a square. Consider the equivalence relation $(-1,y) \sim (1,y)$ and $(x,-1) \sim (x,1)$. Show that $\tilde{Q} = Q / \sim$ is a smooth manifold that coincides with the structure of $\mathbb{R}^2$ at the interior points of $K$. Study the orientability of $\tilde{Q}$.

I see that structure generate a torus, because we glued the square forming a cilinder and then we glued the cone forming a torus (like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289246/why-does-this-equivalence-relation-give-a-torus)).

My doubts are: How can I show the question about structure, I need to construct a map? That map is from square to doble circle $\mathbb{S} \times \mathbb{S}$?

Secondly, after that, can I use a normal function of torus and proof the orientability, like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362204/torus-and-square)? I really need to construct the function?

In advance, thanks for the help :).

Comment: There is a twist involved in gluing the boundary components of the cylinder (not cone). It would be a torus for $(x, -1) \sim (x,1)$.

Comment: Thanks, I edit and correct that :)